# Train a CNN with multiple inputs(1D) and 2D output

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have two sets of inputs of size (500,1) and their label is of size (500,500). I need to train a neural network with the two inputs and map them to the 2D output. How can it be done using a CNN?

Should I use a U-Net or a 1D CNN?
Also, any sample code snippets in tensorflow might be helpful.

Comment: One simple solution could be by starting to merge your inputs (500, 1) (500, 500) to form one single input (500, 501) by concatenation cross columns. After that you need to label your large input in shape of 2D and start training with simple layers before jumping into U-Net and Convolution.

Comment: @user2586955, I have two sets of data, for eg A is 500×1 dimension and B is 500×1 dimension. I also have label of size 500×500 dimension for every A-B pair. I need to make a neural network learn that if the data looks like A-B , the label is like this.

Comment: You could merge A and B to the same input to get (500, 2) data (A in first column and B in second column). Your output will have the shape 500*500.